# Setting bounds for my table view is not working (xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0)

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I would like to set the bounds for my table view (in a UITableViewController) so that it has a smaller width than the screen width (so that a background image can be seen behind the table view).  I use the following line of code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
  [[self tableView] setBounds:CGRectMake(10,44, 300, 460)];
```

However, this line is not working and the tableview still takes up the whole width of the page.

How can I make this work?

Also, as long as I'm on the subject of customizing table views, I would also like to change the font of the text in the cells.  How would I go about doing that?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UITableViewController`'s `view` property is a `UITableView`. So you cannot shrink it's `view` to reveal what's behind, since there is nothing (At least as far as it's concerned) behind it.

There is a relatively easy solution. I'm assuming, based on your code sample that you have a `UITableView` property on your controller named "`tableView`", if not it's creation would be necessary.

1) Change your view controller to be a `UIViewController` subclass instead of a `UITableViewController` subclass. Easily done in the `.h` by replacing `YourClass:UITableViewController` with `YourClass:UIViewController`.

2) In the `.xib` file drag out a new `UIView` to the canvas (not on the tableView).

3) Drag the tableView to be a subview of the view, as shown:
[image]

4) Connect the File's Owner's view property to be the UIView you just added.

5) Check that your connections look something like this:
[image]

With these changes you can now set your **frame** to be smaller than your view's size. You have two choices how to do this:
1) Use code like this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // set background red to see change
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    CGFloat sideMargin = 10;
    CGFloat topBottomMargin = 44;
    CGFloat originX = sideMargin;
        // compute width based on view size
    CGFloat sizeWidth = (self.view.bounds.size.width - (sideMargin * 2));
    CGFloat originY = topBottomMargin;
        // compute height based on view size
    CGFloat sizeHeight = (self.view.bounds.size.height - (topBottomMargin * 2));
        // set tableView frame
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
}
```

2) Change the setting in interface builder directly. Something like:

[image]