# Controlling the total height of the UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which contains a UITableView. I try to control the UITableViewController's view to be only 200px tall. UITableViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200), but I always getting the UITableView to be full height, the table didn't contrainted to 200 px. 
How do I control the total height of the UITableView?

Comment: In what context is the UITableViewController’s view on screen? Is it the window’s `rootViewController`, in a `UINavigationController`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UITableViewController`s `view` property is a `UITableView`. You need to change your `UITableViewController` subclass's superclass to be `UIViewController`. [I answered a question here that explains how to do this, and explains the problem in more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468144/927947)